# Yii framework not checking roles in accessRules

Tags: yii, setstate

I am creating some kind of admin panel in Yii framework, and im setting state at login like this

```
public function authenticate()
{

    $record=AdminTbl::model()->findByAttributes(array('usr'=>$this->username));
    if($record===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if($record->pwd!==$this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$record->id;
        $this->setState('roles','main');
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

I checked if state was really set, echoed out on view. Later i put that role in accessrules()

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view','create','update','admin','delete'),
            'roles'=>array('main'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And i can't access those pages with this user logged in. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

You need to create the *main* role and assign it via the user id.

Comment: In the documentation this not is explained.